# extension 'inboundservices' not found within de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YTypeSystem

Tags: database, sap-commerce-cloud

I am getting this error even after removing all the orphaned types.

> ERROR [hybrisHTTP6] [XMLContentHandler] error in taglistener de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.xml.ItemTypeTagListener@6db66316 at line 425 : error parsing system integrationservices at lines [400-425] : extension 'inboundservices' not found within de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YTypeSystem@58732e23

Full error log:

> de.hybris.bootstrap.xml.UnknownParseError: error parsing system
> integrationservices at lines [400-425] : extension 'inboundservices'
> not found within de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YTypeSystem@58732e23
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: extension 'inboundservices' not
> found within de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YTypeSystem@58732e23  at
> de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.xml.AbstractTypeSystemTagListener.processError(AbstractTypeSystemTagListener.java:44)
> at
> de.hybris.bootstrap.xml.DefaultTagListener.endElement(DefaultTagListener.java:293)
> at
> de.hybris.bootstrap.xml.XMLContentHandler.endElement(XMLContentHandler.java:197)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when itemtypes are moved from one extension to another. In your case you hade itemtypes defined in `inboundservices-items.xml` that are now in `integrationservices-items.xml`.

To find out which exact itemtypes are causing the issue, go to the lines mentioned in the stacktrace, `integrationservices-items.xml` lines 400 to 425.

To fix this you will need to manually delete some entries from the database. with the following, `SQL`, not `FlexibleSearch`, queries via the HAC.

Delete the attributeDescriptors of the moved attributes

```sql
delete
from attributedescriptors
where ownerpkstring in (select pk
                        from composedtypes
                        where internalcodelowercase in ('list','of','affected','attributes'));
```

Delete the composedtypes

```sql
delete
from composedtypes
where internalcodelowercase in ('list','of','affected','attributes');
```

And in case you have moved a deployment table, delete the ydeployments as well

```sql
delete
from ydeployments
where ExtensionName = 'inboundservices'
  AND TableName = 'affectedItemTypeTable'
```

Some additional information that might help can be found [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12752398/error-during-update-system-error-parsing-system-ad.html?childToView=13806187)